# Searching collectionView when search string included on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am using a searchBar to filter collectionView items.

Now I need to enter a text that should be used as search String on a button (BtnCustomSearch) click.
After the button is clicked the search string is put in the searchbar, but the search is not executed.

I am executing the search at

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

Is there a way to force to execute the search when I put the search string when clicking on that button called BtnCustomSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the delegate function of the searchBar like this:

```
  let newString: String = "This is the string to insert in the search bar"
  searchBar.text = newString
  searchBar.delegate?.searchBar?(searchBar, textDidChange: newString)
```